# How to generate output.json instead of output-metadata.json when build APK in androud studio arctic fox 2020.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

In old androud studio and gradle version, it generated `output.json` when I  build APK file

```json
// output.json
[
    {
        "outputType": {
            "type": "APK"
        },
        "apkData": {
            "type": "MAIN",
            "splits": [],
            "versionCode": 25,
            "versionName": "1.8.0",
            "enabled": true,
            "outputFile": "release-v1.8.0-210930.apk",
            "fullName": "release",
            "baseName": "release",
            "dirName": ""
        },
        "path": "release-v1.8.0-210930.apk",
        "properties": {}
    }
]
```

But after I update android studio to arctic fox 2020.3.1, and add jetpack compose library , now only `output-metadata.json` is generated and fields in json are different.

```json
// output-metadata.json
{
  "version": 3,
  "artifactType": {
    "type": "APK",
    "kind": "Directory"
  },
  "applicationId": "com.ts.android.tunnelobj",
  "variantName": "release",
  "elements": [
    {
      "type": "SINGLE",
      "filters": [],
      "attributes": [],
      "versionCode": 26,
      "versionName": "1.11.0",
      "outputFile": "release-v1.11.0-211020.apk"
    }
  ],
  "elementType": "File"
}
```

my gradle-wrapper:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

my sdk version in build.gradle

```
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
        minSdkVersion  21
        targetSdkVersion  27
        versionCode  26
        versionName  "1.1.0"
```

**I have some script tools base on the old `output.json` file. How do I generate `output.json` file in current version, or config `output-metadata.json` fields, instead of refactoring script tools?**